# Why does the value change when I attempt a .attr change in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery script which is supposed to be checking a specific radiobutton from a group based on value. The problem is that everytime I attempt to that specific one it changes the value in all from that group and checks the wrong one.

here is the line i am using to disable:

```
$(".fbh-1").val("val2").attr("checked","checked");
```

and here is the html:

```
<input name="field30" value="val2" type="radio" id="rbt-1" class="rbt-1" />
```

I am not quite sure where I went wrong with this. Any suggestions on the approach I should take on this?

Comment: Well… do they all have the same class of `fbh-1`?

Comment: try .prop("checked", true) on later versions of Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *filter* to `<input>`s with a `value` of `val2`, it’s:

```
$(".fbh-1[value=val2]").attr("checked","checked");
```

Also, use `prop` to set properties:

```
$(".fbh-1[value=val2]").prop("checked", true);
```

Also, don’t use jQuery:

```
document.querySelector(".fbh-1[value=val2]").checked = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".fbh-1").val("val2")
```

This selects *all* `.fbh-1` elements and changes their values.  That's what you told jQuery to do.

I think you wanted:

```
$(".fbh-1[value='val2']")
```

or

```
$(".fbh-1").filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() === 'val2';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the `.val("val2")` is setting the value.

This should be:

Edit: updated sample below to filter out inputs with a value of 'val2', as op asked.

```
$(".fbh-1").not("[value='val2']").attr("checked","checked");
```

Comment: and if it's checking the wrong one, you may need to narrow down your query selectors.  All items with a class of '.fbh-1' will be checked with this code.

Comment: How would i disable anyone in from that group with the value "val2"

Comment: @infomatic, updated to show how to exclude elements by the value attribute.